# Worldizing and reamping experiences?

Tags: worldizing, process, gear, field, recording

More for fun than anything else, i don't need to do it right now, but i was wondering
if anybody here does it or ever tried it, on what kind of sounds? and what kind of playback system, as well as the environment, microphones etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been playing around lately with some "worldizing" techniques, but more for sound design than actual "worldizing".  I loved Murch's interview where he talked about playing back a sound at 4x the speed over a speaker, and recording it back at 4x the speed.  When you play back the recording at normal speed, the sound is very close to the original sound, except that the reverb in the room is now 4x bigger than it would have been if you recorded it at a normal speed.  Pretty awesome idea.  Works really well if you want to really beef something up and want it to be completely organic.  I suppose you can do it fairly well with a Convolution reverb, such as IR or whatever your flavor is, plus a little eq and all, however there's something rewarding about doing it this way.

I've also done a lot of re-amping with guitars and snare drums and stuff when working on music projects, which isn't really Worldizing, but it's a very similar concept.

Comment: I loved that interview, too. I'm still looking for an opportunity to try my hand at that technique. Also, I agree with you re. convolution - it's so easy to reach for that and see it as the solution for whatever reverb trick you're trying to achieve, but getting out into a real acoustic environment is both challenging and rewarding and often times the result will be far better.

Answer (score 4):

Before I had Altiverb I needed to futz a few lines of dialogue to sound like they were coming from a closet. I tried various EQ'ing techniques but was not satisfied with the results. So I ended up putting a speaker in my closet and re-recording the audio through a SM-57 placed about 3 feet from the closet door. I had to tweak the audio a bit once back in Pro Tools but the method worked great!

Nick

Answer (score 2):

I had your typical phone scene in a short film and my phone filtering/distortion attempts weren't working too convincingly... I ended up calling up the studio on my cell phone and playing back the required dialogue lines from the monitors into my cell and back to the DAW via our phone patch box. Worked great and no mics needed (unless you count the cell phone!) - good fix for a pinch.

Not worldizing in the traditional sense, but it made it convincing.

Answer (score 2):

I usually re-amp my synths and record back the sound coming from the speakers, to get rid of the harshness because of the cold synth outputs.

On one occasion I was working with a bathroom scene, and the character was moving around the bathroom as he was talking. I could not achieve a good result with the reverb plug-ins I wanted because the actuall bathrooms are not totally empty places the plug-ins simulate, but has towels, closets, etc, which effects the overall characteristic of the sound.

So I ended up hugging one of my referance speakers, feeding the raw dialogue through it, and X/Y recording in my bathroom while i was walking around with the speakers.

The result was pretty satisfying for me.

Comment: Interesting, old-school approach! Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

OLD THREAD... but thought I'd share....Film I'm working on required the characters to be listening to a radio broadcast through an old radio.  I recorded the radio dialog clean, transferred a copy to my ipod, used a cheap FM-Transmitter, then re-recorded it playing through an old radio... I thought it worked great!